# Can you have more than 1 pet at the same time?

Tags: grim-dawn

I have chosen the path of the Witchblade, which means I am using the Soldier and Sorcerer Class.

I plan on using the summons of the Sorcerer only. Can I summon a Raven and e.g. a Hellhound at the same time though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in fact have both the Raven and the Hellhound at the same time, but only one of each as of my last play of the game (March 2014).

There were rumours of the developers wanting to create some passive traits that would allow you to have more than one at a time, but I'm not sure if they ever did end up doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I dont play Grim Dawn so i dont know about the "path of Witchblade" but however. I found [**this thread**](http://www.grimdawn.com/forums/showthread.php?t=11430) in the official forum were people talk about a "pure summoner" class.

> If you want to be a summoner now I'd first have another build to easily farm content. Try to find the shield that can spawn a hell hound. As well as Salazar's sword to summon a harbinger. Then get the Hell Hound and Raven with its electricity to have a well rounded summoner.

and this one

> Skill wise I think we have 3 summons, perhaps 4 with 1 being not available yet (if it truly exists). Item wise we have 3 types of items that can summon enemies. So in the alpha you can command an army of 2 permanent pets and 3-4 temporary pets.
>
> Item wise we have 3 types of items that can summon enemies. So in the
>   alpha you can command an army of 2 permanent pets and 3-4 temporary
>   pets.

So if i get them right you're able to have more than 1 pet at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Currenty (game ver. **1.0.7.0**): 
You can have as many pets as you can learn.
I am playing **Nerocomancer/Occultist** build and I have 3 pets active + 8 skeletons summoned at once.